# When you press tab icon no not respond

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

But when pressing a long distance from icon work normally.
[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/WC7eho3.gifv)

Comment: Ok, your image explains it quite good. Nonetheless please update your question. We need some code to see how to solve the problem. Please also read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding padding. Also, check your container's styles.